# How can I write to a specific line in a .csv file based on the date using a batch file?

Tags: csv, batch-file

I am very new to batch files and I'm trying to find a way to build a counting batch file that will increment a number in a .csv file - but it must do it on the correct row, based on the date. So I want my .csv file to look like this:

```
2015,10,345
2015,11,287
2015,12,237
2016,01,35
```

It's currently January 2016, so every time my file is run this month I would like it to add 1 to the last line. When it gets to February I'd like it to add a new line with 2016,02,1 and then add to that and so on.

Like I said, I am very new to this! I know the basics of batch files and have tried to find answers, people have asked similar things and I have tried breaking down the responses to work out what I need to do but I can't figure out where to start!

I guess I need to start doing something with FOR /F and set it to skip over lines that don't meet certain criteria?

Answer (score 1):

Batch doesn't have any commands that make it easy to edit text files, or to work with dates. So you must build a solution out of a series of very simple steps.

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "file=test.txt"

:: Get current year and month
for /f "delims=. tokens=1,2" %%A in (
  'wmic os get localDateTime'
) do if "%%B" neq "" set ts=%%A
set "yr=%ts:~0,4%"
set "mo=%ts:~4,2%"

:: Get current count for this month and add 1
set "cnt=0"
for /f "delims=, tokens=3" %%N in (
  'findstr "^%yr%,%mo%," "%file%"'
) do set /a "cnt=%%N+1"

:: Create a new file consisting of all but the current month count,
:: plus the new month count
>"%file%.new" (
  findstr /v "^%yr%,%mo%," "%file%"
  echo %yr%,%mo%,%cnt%
)

:: Move the new file to the original name
move "%file%.new" "%file%" >nul
```